# After segmentation how can I create a mask to select a segmented class?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a CV_32SC1-type Mat, let's call it `segm`. `segm` stores class information after calling the watershed function. Say its possible values are -1(class boundary), 1, 2.

Now, how can I make a mask for the pixels labelled with "2"? That is I need a mat which is 1 iff `segm` is 2, otherwise 0.

I could do this mask with writing a loop, but I think there must be some OpenCV library function that does it, I just could not find it. Does anyone know here the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found it:

```
class_label = 2;
inRange(segm, class_label, class_label, mask_single);
```